# What are the weights of the quadrate formula with weight function $x\mapsto (1-x^2)^{-1/2}$

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

I'm trying to solve this numerical analysis exercise:

[image]

I was able to prove everything until the part marked in red.

I think I need to use this:

http://mathematics.discoursehosting.net/uploads/db1409/459/30801396002e615f.png 
http://mathematics.discoursehosting.net/uploads/db1409/462/2c796a27061f6407.png

So we get an exact result for $T_0$:
$$\int_{-1}^{1} w(x) T_0(x) dx =\sum_{j=0}^{n}W_j T_0 (x_j) $$

An earlier result gives us:
http://mathematics.discoursehosting.net/uploads/db1409/463/3e7d6210f9fc4aad.png

So
$$\int_{-1}^{1} w(x) T_0(x) dx =\sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{\pi}{n+1}  T_0 (x_j) $$

Can I deduce from this that $W_j= \frac{\pi}{n+1}$ ? I remember my teacher saying somthing like this, but I feel like something is missing. This choice for $W_k$ also works to make this equality true:

$$\int_{-1}^{1} w(x) T_k(x) dx =\sum_{j=0}^{n}W_j T_k (x_j) $$

as $\int_{-1}^{1} w(x) T_k(x) dx=0$ and $\sum_{j=0}^{n}T_k (x_j)=0$. But I feel like there may be other set $W'_j$ which would give the same result.